# JavaFX .setStyle inline sub elements

Tags: css, javafx

In order to style the background for many elements in JavaFX, you need to use a css file, or to use .setStyle.

In my case I have to style the background of the dropdown from a `ComboBox`, but I have to use `.setStyle` not a css file (because I have some dynamic colors that will be used to style different GUI elements). The problem here is that if I use the following css code, the function `.setStyle` doesn't recognize it as if I were to use a css file.

```
.setStyle(".combo-box .list-cell{ -fx-background: blue;}");
```

The code would look like this:

```
comboBox.setStyle(".combo-box .list-cell{ -fx-background: #"+ Color1.toString().substring(2) + ";}");
```

`Color1` beeing a `Color` object, that will get a dynamic value depending on the case.

The question is, can I use `.list-cell` inside the function `.setStyle`? If so, how? This would help me with other GUI elements were I'll have to use `.setStyle`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For what I have, I like this solution better.

```
comboBox.setCellFactory(new Callback<ListView<String>, ListCell<String>>() {
    public ListCell<String> call(ListView<String> param) {
        return new ListCell<String>() {
            protected void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
                super.updateItem(item, empty);
                setText(item);
                setBackground(new Background(new BackgroundFill(Color.BLACK, CornerRadii.EMPTY, Insets.EMPTY)));
                setTextFill(Color.BLUE);
            }
        };
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to use a looked-up colors for this. You can assign those using `setStyle` and use them from a CSS stylesheet:

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    ComboBox<String> comboBox = new ComboBox<>();
    comboBox.getItems().addAll("A", "B", "C");

    StackPane root = new StackPane(comboBox);

    // set color
    root.setStyle("cell-color: blue;");

    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 400, 400);
    scene.getStylesheets().add("style.css");

    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.setResizable(false);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

#### style.css

```css
/* default values */
.root {
    cell-color: yellow;
}

/* use color */
.combo-box .list-cell {
    -fx-background: cell-color;
}
```

Comment: You could apply the style programmatically, if you return custom `ListCell`s from the `cellFactory`. But it's actually more complicated to make this work. Most of the looks of JavaFX are achieved at least partially through CSS. In most cases it's simpler to do the same.

Comment: I'll try that too, maybe it will help me in future, so it won't be a waste of time to learn that way also. I don't really want to use css, because the are some users that will mess around with those files, and in return may "break" the app. Thanks.